# Count and list down + advanced features

Tags: shell, wc

I have a few questions:

I have listed the number of lines in the files in /group/book/four/word, sorted by the number of lines they contain using

```
$ wc -l /group/book/four/word/*|sort -n
```

...and I got:

```
2 /group/book/four/word/wer.txt
2 /group/book/four/word/rti.txt
3 /group/book/four/word/cool.txt
```

This is what I wanted! Perfect.

But now I want to make the list generated contain ONLY the file names, e.g like this

```
wer.txt
rti.txt
cool.txt
```

How can I do that using the "od" command?

And how can I use "sed" to remove the numbers at the start of the line of the results I got above? How can I do the same but only for the first two lines?

Comment: You should not mix completely different questions. Delete the shell part and make it a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

You get the list of files with pathname expansion:

```
cd /group/book/four/word
echo *
# or into a file
echo * >/path/to/filelist.txt
```

You can delete everything in a line from the start up to (including) the first space (or group of spaces) with this `sed` command:

```
sed 's/^[^ ]  *//g'
```

I don't see what `od` has to do with that.

`sed` can be limited to the first two lines e.g. by having it exit on the third line:

```
sed -e 3d -e 's/^[^ ]  *//g'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would throw `sed` in directly after `sort` and have it `w`rite out the files as you want them all in one go:

```
wc -l /group/book/four/word/*|sort -n | 
sed 'w ./not_as_yet_touched.txt
 1,2s/^[0-9 ]*//w ./first_two_lines_without_line_numbers_or_leading_spaces.txt
    s|.*/||w ./everything_up_to_first_slash_trimmed.txt'
```

As written, `sed` will still autoprint the results of running all of the above commands, but the results shown on the terminal *(or wherever `stdout` goes)* will only faithfully reflect the contents of the last file. The other two are `w`ritten  at different times during `sed`'s line cycle and so their contents will differ.

About `od` though... hmmm... `od` doesn't really *delimit* data so much as it does *dump* it. You might use `od` in combination with another filter *(such as `sed`)* to clear out the portions of the line as you ask, but without a specific and regular byte count between `/` characters, you probably won't have much use for it. Of course, the final command up there should handle that anyway.